# Find the number of unique users who have visited at least two different countries per site

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct

Find the number of unique users who have visited at least two different countries  per site.
Given timestamp,user,country,site

I think the query should look like this, but it doesnt seem right because it gives very similar answer to number of unique users per site.

```
SELECT site_id, COUNT (DISTINCT user_id) 
FROM SWE 
GROUP BY site_id
HAVING COUNT(country_id) >=2
ORDER BY site_id ASC;
```

Answer (score 3):

Two levels of aggregation is the most natural way to write the query:

```
select site_id, count(*)
from (select user_id, site_id, count(*)
      from swe
      group by user_id, site_id
      having min(country) <> max(country)  -- or count(distinct country) >= 2
     ) us
group by site_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
SELECT A.user_id,B.site_id,COUNT(DISTINCT B.country_id) [Country Visited]
FROM
(
    SELECT user_id 
    FROM SWE
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING COUNT(site_id) = COUNT(DISTINCT site_id)
)A
INNER JOIN SWE B ON A.user_id = B.user_id
GROUP BY A.user_id,B.site_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT B.country_id) >= 2
```